# Arabic Character Sending email isuue in java

Tags: java

I am use below code to send email using java. When i am sending from eclipse it is working fine, but when i create a jar and try to send email it seems Arabic letters are not going, there something ???????? are going. Please help me.

```
package sa.com.medisys.send.mail;

public class SendMail {

String status    = "Mail successfully sent." ;

public SendMail() 
{ 
  log("SendMail()");
}


 public static void send(String SMTPhost,
                      String SMTPort,
                      String FromWithPass,
                      String To,
                      String Subject,
                      String Body,
                      String Attachment,
                      String UserName,
                      String Password ) throws SendMessageException
{    
int StartPos = 0;
int EndPos;
char LastAttachChar;
String Filename;
String operation = null;
String[] processFrom = FromWithPass.split(",");
String from = processFrom[0];
UserName = from;
Password = processFrom[1];
String charset="UTF-8";

//Check if attachment is null
if (Attachment == null||Attachment.equals(""))
{
  EndPos=0;
}
else
{
  EndPos=Attachment.length();
  LastAttachChar = Attachment.charAt(EndPos-1);

  //If Attachment is terminated by comma, delete the last character from attachment
  if (LastAttachChar==',')
  {
    Attachment = Attachment.substring(StartPos,EndPos-1);
    EndPos=Attachment.length();
  }
}

//Get properties and default session for the SMTP server
Properties props = System.getProperties();

props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTPhost);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTPort);
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
//Now try and create the mail message
try
{
  //Create a message
  Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

  //Add sender to message
  operation = "FROM";
  msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
  //Add reciepient list to message
  operation = "TO";
  InternetAddress[] address = InternetAddress.parse(To,false);
  msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
  //Add subject to message
  msg.setSubject(Subject);
  //Add date to message
  msg.setSentDate(new Date());
  //Add a new part to the message
  Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
  {
      System.out.println("BODY::" + Body);
    MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
    //Add the html body to the new part
    mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(new String(Body.getBytes(), "UTF-8"), "text/plain")));

    mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
  }
  //Parse the attachment list and add files to the new part
  if (EndPos != 0)
  {
    //Get the first and last positions of the file separator
    int FilesepPos     = Attachment.indexOf(",");
    int FilesepLastPos = Attachment.lastIndexOf(",");
    //The attachment contains only one file
    if (FilesepPos==-1)
    {
      FilesepPos=EndPos;
      EndPos=0;
    }
    while (true)
    {
      MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
      Filename = Attachment.substring(StartPos,FilesepPos);
      FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(Filename);
      mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
      mbp.setFileName(fds.getName());
      mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
      if (EndPos==0)
      {
        break;
      }
      Attachment = Attachment.substring(FilesepPos+1,EndPos);
      EndPos = Attachment.length();
      if (FilesepPos==FilesepLastPos)
      {
        FilesepPos=EndPos;
        EndPos=0;
      }
      else
      {
        FilesepPos    = Attachment.indexOf(",");
        FilesepLastPos = Attachment.lastIndexOf(",");
      }
    }
  }
  //Add the new part to the message
  msg.setContent(mp);
  //Send the message
  if( UserName == null || Password == null)
    Transport.send(msg);
  else {
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    Transport tr = session.getTransport("smtp");
    tr.connect(SMTPhost, UserName, Password);
    msg.saveChanges();

    tr.sendMessage(msg,msg.getAllRecipients());
    tr.close();

    System.out.println("Mail successfully Sent.");
  }
}
catch (AddressException aex)
{
  throw new Exception("Email Address error " + operation + " value > " + aex.getMessage());
}
catch (MessagingException mex)
{
  Exception nested = mex.getNextException();
  if(nested == null) nested = mex ;
  throw new Exception(nested.getMessage());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  throw new Exception(ex.toString());
}
}

void log( String sMessage )
{
System.out.println( sMessage ) ;
}

private String getBody() {
    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("D:\\empty\\email.txt"), "UTF-8");
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            test.append(scanner.nextLine());
            test.append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return test.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  String sub = "أخطاء المطبعية في عنوان  خطاء";
  String msg = new SendMail().getBody();
try {

    new SendMail().send("mail.doamin.com", "25", "email@doamin.com,PASSWORD", "email@gmail.com", sub, msg, null, "", "");

    System.out.println("Send");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Send Failed");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Note that you're never using `charset` (at least in this code)

Comment: i have use charset, but in hard code see, there is UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

`Body.getBytes()` gets the bytes of the string in whatever your JVM's default charset is, so you are likely discarding the Arabic characters there.

Try:

```
new ByteArrayDataSource(Body, "text/plain")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i have tried this. Not working.

Comment: How about with `"text/plain; charset=UTF-8"` as the MIME type?

Comment: Well, I tried; I'm just going on documentation here :) I can assure you, though, that `new String(Body.getBytes(), "UTF-8")` is at best redundant (if your JVM's default charset is UTF-8, it basically copies the string) and at worst lossy (if the string contains codepoints not representable in your JVM's default charset).